# Unusual ant behavior with presetdef and antcall

Tags: ant, build

Consider the following excerpt from an ant build.xml:

```xml
<presetdef name="echo1def">
    <echo message="prop: ${foo}" />
</presetdef>

<presetdef name="echo2def">
    <sequential>
        <echo message="prop: ${foo}" />
    </sequential>
</presetdef>

<target name="echotarget1">
    <property name="foo" value="bar" />
    <echo1def/>
</target>

<target name="echotarget2">
    <property name="foo" value="bar" />
    <echo2def/>
</target>

<target name="echo1">
    <antcall target="echotarget1" />
</target>

<target name="echo2">
    <antcall target="echotarget2" />
</target>
```

Calling any of {echotarget1, echotarget2, echo1} produce the expected output of `prop: bar`.  Calling echo2, however, produces `prop: ${foo}`.

Why can't the `echo2def` resolve the `${foo}` property?  It's defined immediately before, in the same project (i.e., not even on the other side of the antcall). The echo1 call, which does the same thing except the presetdef is not wrapped in `<sequential>`, has no issue.

Finally,

```
<target name="echo3">
    <property name="foo" value="baz" />
    <antcall target="echotarget2" />
</target>
```

reports `prop: baz` - so the property from the antcalling project *can* be seen, even though it is defined after the presetdef is.

Answer (score -1):

Just get rid of `<sequential>` in your echo2def presetdef, means :

```
<presetdef name="echo2def">
 <echo message="prop: ${foo}" />
</presetdef>
```

and all will work as expected.
It's because property scopes exist at Apache Ant's various "block" levels including sequential, that's how i.e. the [local task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) (new in Ant 1.8.0) works.

`antcall` opens a new project scope, without antcall - means calling those targets echotarget1 and echotarget2 directly - it works also, resolving the property ${foo}.

Comment: ... but the question stands - presetdef can use <sequential> or any other task - I just used <sequential> because it was the easiest, but you can encounter the same issue with <if> or anything else.

Comment: you are right, it may contain any nested task but see my edited answer

Comment: OK, but then explain why echo1 works.  It also uses antcall and is otherwise identical to the other example.

Comment: I don't think the local comment is relevant - it only talks about *shadowing* in nested scopes, but here the inner thing is even seeing the thing defined in the outer scope.  It's pretty easy to show that generally targets do see properties defined in "parent" ant processes even through an antcall.

Comment: answer 1 : echo1 works, as it's calling echotarget1 which is calling the echo1def presetdef which * doesn't use sequential *
answer 2 : yes normally properties are available when using antcall and inheritAll=true (which is the default setting) - but not when sequential is involved like in your example.
question : why don't you use sequential inside presetdef ? Makes no sense to me.
After all you should avoid antcall for many reasons, use macrodef (since Ant 1.6.x) instead.

Comment: should read: ...why do you use sequential inside presetdef ..
Search for antcall here at stackoverflow to get some aspects about the pros and (many) cons of antcall

Comment: The example was to illustrate the behavior and ask why.  The actual case that I ran into is more complicated, involving a nested <if> and other methods.

It's worth nothing that macrodef doesn't exhibit this problem.

It's almost like the contents of the presetdef are resolved, including properties, when the presetdef is processed, at which point foo is not defined.